# SharedViewModel for Fragments with LiveData

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

I am experimenting **SharedViewModel** with live data for **fragments**

I use **getViewLifeCycleOwner** as owner of live data in Fragment 1.

When I move to Fragment 2 from fragment 1 and, again when I come back to Fragment 1 liveData in **Fragment 1** is triggered **automatically**

Any reason why this is happening?

### This is how I initialise viewModel in onCreate of Activity

```
private void initViewModel() {
    loginViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
    loginActivityBinding.setViewModel(loginViewModel);
}
```

### Initialisation of ViewModel in onCreateView of Fragment

```
loginViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(LoginViewModel.class);
    loginMobileNumberBinding.setViewModel(loginViewModel);
```

### Observing viewModel in Fragment 1

```
loginViewModel.getLoginClicked().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),aBoolean {
        if(aBoolean != null && aBoolean) {

        }
    });
```

The live data for this observer is triggered onClick of a button. This observer is getting triggered when I come back from Fragment 2 to Fragment 1 automatically.

Comment: Can you show your sample code?

Comment: I faced a similar kind of problem thus switched to simple viewmodel and made its static reference in the activity and used it later.

Comment: I have added the sample code snippets too..

Comment: Have you tried setting the viewModel in Fragment's onCreate instead of onCreateView?

Comment: Yeah Tried it too.. still the same

Comment: Tried it not working